# Critique some Ruby + RSpec Code for a SERP checker

Tags: ruby

I found a SERP checker written in PHP and I decided, in order to better learn to program, I would re-write it in Ruby.

All I have written so far takes a list of keywords that a user inputs and cleans the list and turns each keyword into a url for Google search.

Here is the code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rspec'
get '/serp_checker' do
  "<form action='/ranked' method='post'>
  <label for='keyword'>Keyword</label>
  <textarea name='keyword' id='keyword' type='text' /></textarea>
  <label for='url'>URL</label>
  <input name='url' id='url' type='text' />
  <input type='submit' value='Go!' />
  </form>"
end

def clean_up_keywords(str)
  str.gsub("\n", ",").delete("\r").split(',')
end

def clean_up_list(arr)
  arr.reject(&:empty?).each(&:lstrip!)
end

def make_strings_url_friendly(arr)
  arr.each do |e|
    e.gsub!(" ", "+")
  end
end

def make_urls(arr)
  arr.map {|e| "http://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=" + e}
end

post '/ranked' do
  dirty_list = clean_up_keywords(params[:keyword])
  clean_list = clean_up_list(dirty_list)
  url_ready_list = make_strings_url_friendly(clean_list)
  url_list = make_urls(url_ready_list)
end
```

Here is the spec:

```
require_relative '../lib/rankypanky.rb'

describe "#clean_up_keywords" do
  it "should push items separated by a newline into array as separate items" do
    clean_up_keywords("apples\noranges").should == ["apples", "oranges"]
  end
  it "should delete all \r chars" do
    clean_up_keywords("Chat\r").should == ["Chat"]
  end
  it "should push items separated by commas into an array" do
    clean_up_keywords("Chat, Meta, About").should == ["Chat", " Meta", " About"]
  end
  it "should push items separated ONLY by a \s char into array as one item" do
    clean_up_keywords("New York, apples").should == ["New York", " apples"]
  end
end

describe "#clean_up_list" do
  it "should not include empty strings/items in array" do
    clean_up_list(["apples", "", "oranges"]).should == ["apples", "oranges"]
  end
  it "should remove any leading white space from items in array" do
    clean_up_list([" oranges", "apples"]).should == ["oranges", "apples"]
  end
end

describe "#make_strings_url_friendly" do
  it "should replace /s with a +" do
    make_strings_url_friendly(["oranges apples"]).should == ["oranges+apples"]
  end
end

describe "#make_urls" do
  it "should append array items to http://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=" do
    make_urls(["pie"]).should == ["http://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=pie"]
  end
end
```

Basically I'm looking for any better ways to do this as well as whether my code meets hmmm standards... just some general critique. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I see you haven't got any response on this for a long while, so I'll give it a try.

I don't really see anything to pick on when it comes to style or technique. To me this looks very good. A few questions though:

1. why do you `require "rspec"` in the controller code? Shouldn't this be in the test code instead?
2. You don't do any attempt to sanitize or verify that the code works with non-english characters, or other characters that may cause trouble. What if someone type `"tørris&message=<script>alert("Hoy there");</script>"` in the input form? (I guess google will sanitize it, but it would probably be better to do it before passing the url to them.)